# How do I know if my SVR is over-fitting?

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn, overfitting

```
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
model = SVR()
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression)
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('sel',fs), ('svr', model)])

grid = dict()

grid['sel__k'] = [i for i in range(1, X_train.shape[1]+1)]


search = GridSearchCV(
        pipeline,
        param_grid={
            'svr__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], ##Regularization
            'svr__epsilon': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
            'svr__gamma': [0.0001,  0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]


        },
        scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
        return_train_score=True,
        verbose=1,
        cv=5,
        n_jobs=-1)



# perform the search
results = search.fit(X_train, y_train)
model = results.best_estimator_ # This is your model

#print(results.cv_results_.keys())
#print(results.cv_results_["mean_train_score"].shape)  
#print(results.cv_results_["mean_test_score"].shape)#

#print(results.cv_results_["mean_train_score"])
#print(results.cv_results_["mean_test_score"])


# summarize best
print('Best MAE: %.3f' % results.best_score_)
print('Best Config: %s' % results.best_params_)

# summarize all
means = results.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
params = results.cv_results_['params']
for mean, param in zip(means, params):
    print(">%.3f with: %r" % (mean, param))


# save the model to disk
filename = 'svr_v2_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

You can see towards the end, I have a lot of commented-out code for different scores that I've gotten from looking around at other people's answers and trying to understand how to know if my model is overfitting my training data. I am totally confused by which score which tell me if the model is over-fitting.

Can anyone explain to me, which score/lines of code do I check, to tell me whether my model is overfit (note that this is regression and not classification)?

Comment: You cannot diagnose overfitting simply from metric values; its tell-tale signature is, *validation error starts increasing while training error keeps decreasing*.

Comment: So I was actually originally looking to draw some sort of ROC/AUC curve which I think is similar-ish to what you're saying (to check error rates over time), and I found you can't do them for regression (which makes sense I guess). Could you explain how I check this? I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184103/why-the-error-on-a-training-set-is-decreasing-while-the-error-on-the-validation) but it's just explaining the issue, would you know what the plot/library etc I'm meant to be using to check this is? Thanks.

Comment: Just to update, I've found throughout the day that I think I want to plot my training curve and my validation curve on one plot, but I can't find a code sample that would demonstrate how to do this. if you know of one I'd appreciate it.